# How can I add 2 byte CRC at the end of File

Tags: c, crc

I have one encrypted file named encrypt.
Here I calculated crc 16 for this file and store this crc result in `unsigned short` this unsigned short size is `2 byte(16 bits)`.
Now I want to append 2 byte of crc value at the end of this file and read these last 2 bytes from file and have to compare this crc so how can I achieve this thing?

I used this code

```
fseek(readFile, filesize, SEEK_SET);
fprintf(readFile,"%u",result);
```

Here filesize is my file original encrypted file size and after this i add `result` which is `unsigned short` but in file its write 5 bytes.

file content after this

```
testsgh
30549
```

original file data is `testsgh` but here crc is 30459 I want to store this value in 2 byte. so how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open the file in binary append mode:

```
FILE *out = fopen("myfile.bin", "ab");
```

This will eliminate the need to seek to the end.

Then, you need to use a direct write, not a print which converts the value to a string and writes the string. You want to write the bits of your `unsigned short` checksum:

```
const size_t wrote = fwrite(&checksum, sizeof checksum, 1, out);
```

This succeeded if and only if the value of `wrote` is 1.

However, please note that this risks introducing endianness errors, since it writes the value using your machine's local byte order. To be on the safe side, it's cleaner to decide on a byte ordering and implement it directly. For big-endian:

```
const unsigned char check_bytes[2] = { checksum >> 8, checksum & 255 };
const size_t wrote = fwrite(check_bytes, sizeof check_bytes, 1, out);
```

Again, we expect `wrote` to be 1 after the call to indicate that both bytes were successfully written.

Comment: Here i want to run this utility on cross platform

Comment: Here in my case i have to write 2 bytes than i have to put 2 instead of 1 in fwrite() function ?

Answer (score 0):

you can write single characters with **%c** formating. e.g.

```
fprintf(readfile, "%c%c", result % 256, result / 256)
```

btw: **readfile** is misleading, when you write to it :-)

Comment: Here all other suggest me fwrite

Answer (score 0):

Use fwrite(), not fprintf. I don't have access to a C compiler atm but fwrite(&result, sizeof(result), 1, readFile); should work.

Comment: Thanks For reply but here i want to write 2 bytes data so i have to put 2 instead of 1?

Comment: No, the second parameter is the size of each object we are writing, the third is the number of such objects. We're writing one 2-byte object, so size is 2 and count is 1. The "2 bytes" comes from sizeof(result), as result is of type short, this is 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
unsigned char c1, c2;
c1 = (unsigned char)(result >> 8);
c2 = (unsigned char)( (result << 8) >> 8);
```

and then append `c1` and `c2` at the end of the file. When you read the file back, just do the opposite:

```
result = ( (unsigned)c1 << 8 ) + (unsigned)c2;
```

Hope that helps.